# Bootstrap tabs not working the first time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I am trying to implement two basic tabs and panels. The panel does not show the content(Page 1) on page load. However, clicking on the other tab works fine with the right content(Page 2) and then going back to the first tab works fine(Page 1).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane">
        Page 1
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane">
        Page 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the active class for the content panel.
You need the following to show the panel1 content by default:

```
<div id="panel1" class="tab-pane show active">...
```

Comment: Thank you. But this solution causes another issue. While it fixes the issue with the initial load, the tab 2 has both Page 1 and Page 2.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't. You tab-content should look like this:

`<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane show active">
        Page 1
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane">
        Page 2
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: If you find that page 1 does not clear, ensure the panel and the initial tab button are both set to active.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more details because your code is working fine

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane show active">
       This is the content of page1............................
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane">
       This is the content of page2............................
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your's has the same issue. There is nothing printed when the page loads. It's only on click of the link that text appears.

Comment: @TheFallenOne Thanks for pointing it out , i edited my snippet